# Is this possible & accomplishable with Highchart v4 ?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been struggling to apply the following chart

[image]

But so far, it's seem to me that's it's impossible to:

1/ Implement the Target & Range. Basically it's not really a data point but just an image to place on top of the `Difference from Target` to clarify if `Difference from Target` is negative or positive compare to `Actual`

[image]

2/ Place the legend in front of each bar, and format it like follwing:

[image]

Comment: Short answer: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Could you please shed some light on this ?

Comment: I would think stacked bar charts would be the way to do this. Adding values do category labels (your 2nd requirement) is easy using the xAxis label formater. Check the API for specifics. What have you tried? Is there a specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Thanks @wergeld, my problem is that I can't lay 2 layers of xAxis label ? it's `Stocks        >> Actual | Target`

Comment: @nqtien310, yes it is. Via a plugin (http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories).

Comment: Thanks a lot @wergeld, that really saved me.